# How can I calculate the y intercept of a line with the slope and x intercept?

Tags: linear-algebra

this question might seem silly but I don't know how I can solve for the y-intercept with the slope and x-intercept already given. I don't know what formula to use and then how to translate that into Java code. I have already tried `xInt = ((0 - p1.getY()) / this.slope) + p1.getX();` and it seemed to work for the x-intercept but if I do the same for the y it doesn't seem to work and I just get the same answer I did when it solved for the x-intercept. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what you have have tried, so we have mroe context of what you know related to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose you are given the slope $m$ and the $x$-intercept $a$ (that means $y=0$ when $x=a$). You want to find the $y$-intercept $b$. If you write down the slope-intercept form $$y=mx+b$$
and you know $y=0$ when $x=a$, do you see how this lets you find $b$ in terms of $m$ and $a$?

Comment: Are you saying you want me to multiply the slope by the x-intercept and thats how ill find my y-intercept?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the slope of a line is determined by any two points on that line: It's the horizontal component of the distance between the two points divided by the vertical component.

Now apply this with one of the two points being the intersection of your line with the $x$-axis and the other point being the intersection of your line with the $y$-axis. Knowing the $x$-intercept, you know the horizontal component of the distance between your two points. Knowing the slope, you can get the vertical component of that distance. You also know the $y$-coordinate of your first point (namely $0$). So that gives you the $y$-coordinate of your second point, which is the $y$-intercept.